# .htaccess redirect /wp-login.php/ to /login/ but keep the text after that?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to do a redirect (ideally .htaccess) from page:
`https://mypage.com/wp-login.php` TO `https://mypage.com/login`
this scenario has thousands of examples on the internet, but what if a link has redirect, for example:

```
https://mypage.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=someurl
```

and I would like to keep the end (redirect) but only change the `wp-login.php` bit to `login`?

Comment: The original query string _automatically_ gets appended to the substitution URL, if you don’t explicitly specify a new one.

Comment: Ok so I have: RewriteRule ^login/(.*)$ /wp-login.php/$1 [QSA,L]
Now how do I make /login/ to display what /login/ originally displays and not the /wp-admin.php/ page?

Comment: Huh? _“Now how do I make /login/ to display what /login/ originally displays”_ - by not rewriting in the first place? I don’t get what you want here.

Comment: wp-login.php displays standard wp login page. My custom login page "login" displays custom login page.

When changed the rewrite rules and made wp-login.php to be login, login page now instead of displaying my custom login page displays wordpress' standard login page.

Comment: Sounds like you are currently rewriting in the opposite direction of what you actually want …?

Comment: haha it seems like it but if I redirect the other way round then it results with having my custom login page at address: wp-login.php lol

EDIT: I MESSED UP SO BADLY AND EMBARASSED MYSELF HERE. Man god bless you. It works but I just did it wrong lol

Answer (score 1):

here is complete solution to remove php extension with query extension.

```
function strip_php_extension()  
{  

$uri= basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
 $ext = substr(strrchr($uri, '.'), 1);  
 if ($ext == 'php')  
 {  
  $url1 = substr($uri, 0, strrpos($uri, '.')); 
 if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
  {
    $url=$url1 ."?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 
  } 
   else 
  {
    $url=$url1; 
  } 

  redirect($url);  
    }  
 }  

  function redirect($url)  
   {  
  if (!headers_sent())  
   {  
  /* If headers not yet sent => do php redirect */  
  header('Location: '.$url);  
  exit;  
  }  
 else  
 {
  /* If headers already sent => do javaScript redirect */  
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';  
   echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';  
  echo '</script>';  

  /* If javaScript is disabled => do html redirect */  
  echo '<noscript>';  
  echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='.$url.'" />';  
   echo '</noscript>';  
   exit;  
    }  
    } 

   //call function simply
   strip_php_extension();

 //And Write this code in your .htaccess file

    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

   Thanks.
```

Comment: Ok so I have: RewriteRule ^login/(.*)$ /wp-login.php/$1 [QSA,L] Now how do I make /login/ to display what /login/ originally displays and not the /wp-admin.php/ page?

Comment: create any new file and paste code and include this file in your login page and call function(which is mentioned in below code)

Comment: Like:-remove_extension.php   in this file paste both function  strip_php_extension and redirect. And this file include in your login.php file and call function   strip_php_extension();

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

To redirect wp-login.php to login, I added below code into .htaccess (root folder)

```
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php/(.*)$ /login/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks to this code if there's a ?redirect_to=SMTH it stays at the back of the url.